# Imagem sem qualidade - Safari

Tags: imagem, safari

Imagem da logo do site no qual estou desenvolvendo perde qualidade quando abro o site no Safari.

Alguém já passou por isso e sabe como resolver?

Comment: Defina "perder qualidade". Talvez ajude colocar uma imagem de exemplo aqui - faça uma imagem qualquer com as mesmas dimensões (e no caso de um formato que não seja lossless, com a mesma qualidade) e poste aqui, caso não queira identificar o logo de seu cliente.

Comment: Resumindo, ela fica distorcida, serrilhada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é o Safari, é que [computadores Macs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) mais modernos estão usando [tela retina ou ecrã retina](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tela_retina), as imagens ficam um pouco desfocado geralmente se usado em *backgrounds*, duas soluções são:

1. **Imagem com dobro do tamanho:**

   Por exemplo, suponha que você quer criar uma imagem com *442px x 116px*, então você cria ela com o dobro do tamanho (*885px x 233px*) e usa `background-size` para reduzir pela metade:

   ```css
   .logo, .logo-original {
       background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXDKB.png) no-repeat;
   }

   .logo {
       background-size: 442px 116px;
       width: 442px;
       height: 116px;
   }

   .logo-original {
       width: 885px;
       height: 233px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="logo"></div>
   <hr>
   <div class="logo-original"></div>
   ```

   Se usar `<img>` pode experimentar usar `width=""`, assim:

   ```html
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXDKB.png" width="442">
   ```
2. **Usar SVG:**

   O SVG é uma [imagem vetorial](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desenho_vetorial), podendo ser redimensionada sem perda de qualidade (apesar que em alguns casos a imagem pode parecer ter um efeito borrado quando muito pequena, mas depende do desenho):

   ```css
   .logo, .logo-original {
       background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=2bb144720a66) no-repeat;
   }

   .logo {
       background-size: 442px 116px;
       width: 442px;
       height: 116px;
   }

   .logo-original {
       width: 885px;
       height: 233px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="logo"></div>
   <hr>
   <div class="logo-original"></div>
   ```

Comment: Ah sim, entendi.

O que estou fazendo é exatamente esse esquema de usar uma imagem bem maior e diminuir no código, mas na verdade ela está sendo colocada como img no html, não como background no css.

Estou desenvolvendo em Wordpress, e usando o tema padrão da empresa que trabalho, ou seja, o lugar de colocar a logo já é pré definido e não aceita SVG.

Comment: @PeterRoberto Basta aplicar com `<img src="image-600px_400px.png" width="300" height="200">`, claro que sendo imagens não vetoriais podem não funcionar bem, de qualquer forma se o Wordpress não permite usar SVG então não tem o que fazer infelizmente.

Comment: Sim, sim, muitíssimo obrigado irmão!